# i would like to Identify an IC with top marking MQ1CE

Tags: integrated-circuit

I would like to identify an IC named MQ1CE. I hope this is a micro controller.

Searching the internet I have got several answers such as a micro-controller, a knee-slapper (I don't know what that is), a coil serial to SPI converter and similar, etc.

The majority are referring to a micro-controller. I would like to know which one this IC is, and get a datasheet.

[image: MQ1CE IC Image]

Comment: Please provide more context.

Comment: I have captured this image from a module. I know that this module is used to test indication LEDs. In this module there are only two ICs and 5 passives, 7 electronic components in total. Functionally one IC must be a photo-detector [array detector 64 in total i believe]. On searching for this sensor I am getting different kinds of detector which provides different kinds of outputs and with different kinds of controls.

Comment: Detector array needs to be switched and read. then there should be and an ADC for conversion. the module has only one output pin. I have information that output from the module is frequency modulated signal with varying voltage which is also corresponding to incident light. I am curios to know about this second chip MQ1CE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably MC68HC908QT1 (CDW package), but I don't see the exact marking scheme specified on the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC68HC908QY4.pdf).

Comment: I have seen images of this IC in alibaba.com, ifi use this chip, to program this IC should i have to follow NXP IDE or is there any different IDE I must follow.

Comment: You can use CodeWarrior, there are probably others such as IAR. And probably command line compilers as there were from 68HC05.